# How can I set up a Influxdb database based on workspace name?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform script where I have to set up an Influxdb server and I want to create different databases based on the workspace name. Is it possible to create a map in the variables file to allocate a database name and look it up from a different variable within the same file?

```
Ex: 
var file: 

variable "influx_database" "test" {
 name = "${lookup(var.influx_database_name, terraform.workspace)}
}

variable "influx_database_name" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    dump = "dump_database"
    good = "good_database"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local variable like below,

```tf
locals {
  influx_database_name = "${lookup(var.influx_database_name, terraform.workspace)}"
}

variable "influx_database_name" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    default = "default_database"
    dump    = "dump_database"
    good    = "good_database"
  }
}

output "influx_database_name" {
  value = "${local.influx_database_name}"
}
```

local.influx_database_name is defined by workspace name.